# yum-security for CentOS?

Tags: centos, redhat

Last time I checked I was able to install yum-security in CentOS but since it doesn't use the official redhat mirrors I was unable to get it to actually work. Is there a way to make yum-security work or is there an alternative to yum-security on CentOS?

Comment: For reference, [related question](https://serverfault.com/q/762006/1223) from 2016.

Answer (score 1):

For **Centos 6**, **Centos 7** and **Centos 8** the easiest way is to use Steve Meier's [Updateinfo: a yum repository with CentOS Errata information](https://updateinfo.cefs.steve-meier.de/).

It's a ready yum repo served and updated by the author of the CEFS project.

It is a paid service but as of now it costs only a mere $3 per month for an unlimited number of servers (but using a mirror for a big fleet is recommended).

Note that it's the same thing as [you can do yourself according to dsmsk80's answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/837440/190032). But don't you prefer to support the enthusiast who made this solution possible instead? :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy alternative to this redhat feature with centos.

The only alternative I know so far is to manually list the rpms affected by one or more CVE and update only them.

Comment: I am sorry but this is simply not true. For many years you could have used [CEFS](http://cefs.steve-meier.de/) project and since 2017 you can use [Updateinfo](https://updateinfo.cefs.steve-meier.de/). See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1037208/190032) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, yum-security is [not supported](http://www.linux-archive.org/centos/256153-yum-security-plugin.html) on CentOS :(

However, this hacked [alternative](http://www.linux-archive.org/centos/291796-yum-security.html) might work for you.

Comment: FYI, the second link (http://www.linux-archive.org/centos/291796-yum-security.html ) is a 404.

Answer (score -1):

These days yum-security works fine on CentOS, you can install it from [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)

Example on CentOS 6:

```
$ rpm -q yum-plugin-security
yum-plugin-security-1.1.30-14.el6.noarch
```

(On CentOS 5 the package is called yum-security)

```
$ sudo yum update --security
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
Limiting packages to security relevant ones
epel/updateinfo                                                                                                                                                                                                         | 724 kB     00:00     
No packages needed for security; 141 packages available
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. On CentOS 6, I installed httpd-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm , which has had several security updates such as [CESA-2013:1156](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2013-August/019902.html). `yum update --security` still says `No packages needed for security`. `yum update` will update httpd just fine. I'll note that `yum-plugin-security` *does* work on Scientific Linux.

Comment: I'm not sure what it's actually doing on the backend, because it **does** list some of the packages that need updating. Problem is it leaves other important packages that need updating out, so it gives a false sense of security. Which, arguably, is worse than if it simply reliably did nothing.

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work is that CentOS doesn't publish which updates are security updates in its repo metadata. EPEL does, though, so occasionally you see an update via this process and may be misled into thinking that it is doing what you want.