# Scientific Linux 6.5: update ONLY kernel security fixes

Tags: security, yum, kernel, scientific-linux

We have machines running Scientific Linux (SL) 6.5 release (`2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64`) and would like to update just the kernel for security fixes. I have checked [another post](https://serverfault.com/questions/369833/automatically-check-for-security-updates-on-centos-or-scientific-linux) related to this, but that does clarify if we can do security updates on an individual package basis.

For my SL 6.5 box, I would like to update to `kernel-2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

Then just run the command as follows.

```
yum update kernel-2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64
```

Dependencies are pulled in automatically and you should accept them.

Comment: yum does not list `kernel-2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64` even though I can see that kernel is the [baseurl for the repository for SL 6.5](http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.5/x86_64/updates/security/). Have tried `yum  list kernel --showduplicates` but can only see `kernel-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6`