# Getting Centos Security Updates as in 2016

Tags: centos, security, centos6

I have been searching around in the net and in StackExchange as well, and found out `yum-plugin-security` although can be installed but it is actually not functioning for Centos-base repositories, back to 2013 and 2014. Referring to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/369833/automatically-check-for-security-updates-on-centos-or-scientific-linux) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/2673/yum-security-for-centos).

I have tested again myself with my Centos 6.6 and found out as in 2016 now, `yum-plugin-security` is still not functioning. This can be tested using the latest most heat issue of the DROWN attack of *openssl*.

First get the version of *openssl* installed:

```
4977-20[13:59:19 root@lye-vm ~]# rpm -qa openssl
openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.5.x86_64
```

Then find any updates available for openssl:

```
4978-21[14:09:37 root@lye-vm ~]# yum list updates openssl*
Loaded plugins: security
Updated Packages
openssl.x86_64    1.0.1e-42.el6_7.4      updates
```

Ok, so there is one. Then find it with `yum-plugin-security` tools `updateinfo`:

```
4979-22[14:09:42 root@lye-vm ~]# yum updateinfo list security
Loaded plugins: security
updateinfo list done
4980-23[14:09:46 root@lye-vm ~]#
```

So there is none shown by 'updateinfo'. (If using `yum --security check-update` it will list out all updates available, which is not functioning so well).

I wish to know is it true there is NO WAY we can get the **Security Updates** by using `yum` commands ? or there is a  way and I did something wrong ?

My purpose is to only update Centos with **security related** updates. At the moment what I can do is manually subscribe to [Centos-announce mailing list](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/) and look for those thread with keyword *Security Update*, such as [this](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2016-March/021712.html) for the openssl DROWN attack.

Comment: In my experience, unless you have manually enabled the CR (continuous release) repo(s), `yum update` only picks up security updates to core unless there's a new point release of the OS, at which time you get al the other updates.  Or are you asking how to stay at a particular point release of CentOS and stay secure, long-term?

Comment: @MadHatter: Yes, I need to stay at a particular point of CentOS and only get Security Updates, not other bugfix or enhancement.

Comment: That is not the way CentOS/RH is designed to be used, and you cannot, and shouldn't try, to do this; see [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/535615/55514) for more details, but in brief, your OS will be end-of-lifed immediately the next point release is out.

Comment: My question is not about staying at a particular point of 6.x, mine is staying at a point where only installed patches we tested with our application. Thus able to know what type of patches they are is vital. 

Servers are being used for numerous purpose and it need to coordinate well with other software running on it, be it a web server or a db. Some other software might not work well with other enhancement of the patches before they are tested.

Comment: So that's why we need to have the ability to categorize the patches and schedule to test that later . But a Security Updates is vital to be patched immediately to avoid exploited especially in the production server. I am not sure why are you saying Centos/RH is not designed for such purpose. Redhat is able to do that at [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10021), but sadly not Centos.

Comment: In fact this is a very common practise. Other distro does that, for instance [ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194/how-can-i-install-just-security-updates-from-the-command-line), [slackware](http://www.slackware.com/security/list.php?l=slackware-security&y=2016)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the other answer, CentOS [does not provide](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=59369) security-related information. In other words, it does not mark updated as "security updates", with the consequence that `yum --security update` [does nothing](https://www.caseylabs.com/centos-automatic-security-updates-do-not-work/).

However, a solution exists: we can leverage [CEFS's work](http://cefs.steve-meier.de/) to extract the required security information, feeding them into `Spacewalk` or, very recently, directly into [`yum`](https://updateinfo.cefs.steve-meier.de/). So, all you need now (October 2017) to have security updates is to install the required `yum-security` plugin and enable the [updateinfo repository](https://updateinfo.cefs.steve-meier.de/).

As historical notes/project, and as another means to feed the required metadata into `yum`, be sure to give a look [here](https://github.com/wied03/centos-package-cron) and [here](http://blog.vmfarms.com/2013/12/inject-little-security-in-to-your.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `--security` option.

```
# yum --security update
Loaded plugins: etckeeper, fastestmirror, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.cs.pitt.edu
 * epel: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.dattobackup.com
 * updates: mirror.cogentco.com
Resolving Dependencies
Limiting packages to security relevant ones
No packages needed for security; 1 packages available
```

But keep in mind that:

- CentOS repos do not tag any updates as security updates.
- If you use third party repos, they might not tag all of their security updates as such.

So you may need to apply additional updates.

Comment: hi Michael, I have tried that one, it didn't work for Centos-base package. It does work for EPEL though. You can tried with the latest openssl security updates.